# Cycles: Rendered Image's lighting doesn't illuminate as much as render view's lighting

Tags: cycles-render-engine, lighting

For some reason I can't figure out, my render view does not match my rendered image when it comes to lighting.  I've tried all sorts of different render configurations, lighting options (pictured below is an emission material on the inside of the jack-o-lantern, but I've tried putting spot lighting inside as well to similar effect), nothing seems to make a difference.

Render view:

[image]

Actual rendered image:

[image]

How do I get the rendered image to match what I'm looking at in the render view?

[Link to .blend file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ba3vypzk2yz519w/Halloween.blend?dl=0)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have hidden an object in the viewport, but not in the render. First enable the restriction toggle *Disable in Renders* (camera icon). Then disable rendering for object *Curve.011* in the *jack o lantern pattern 1.svg* collection.

[image: Restriction toggle]
[image: Disable in render]
[image: Render]